# How to deploy Next js 13 App on Azure web app with different(dev ,test, prod) environments

Tags: next.js, azure-devops, development-environment, azure-appservice

I am trying to deploy Next js 13 app via Self Hosting(Azure) with different environments.
I have tried including Server.js with dev and prod environments with custom web configuration.

> Server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001
const app = next({ dev,port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()
  server.get('/p/:id', (req, res) => {
    const actualPage = '/post'
    const queryParams = { title: req.params.id }
    app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)
  })
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:' + port)
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})`
```

> Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind IIS or IIS Express. For more information, visit: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config--><configuration> <system.webServer> <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support --> <webSocket enabled="false" /> <handlers> <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module --> <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/> </handlers> <rewrite> <rules> <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging --> <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" /> </rule> <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder --> <rule name="StaticContent"> <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/> </rule> <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point --> <rule name="DynamicContent"> <conditions> <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/> </conditions> <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/> </rule> </rules> </rewrite> <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it --> <security> <requestFiltering> <hiddenSegments> <remove segment="bin"/> </hiddenSegments> </requestFiltering> </security> <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched --> <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" /> <!-- You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options: * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options --> <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>--> </system.webServer></configuration>
```

> Package.json

```
{
  "name": "quickview",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "buildDev": "env-cmd -f .env.development next build",
    "buildStaging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging next build",
    "buildProd": "env-cmd -f .env.production next build",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "startProd": "node server.js",
    "format": "prettier  --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}\""
  },
```

Error Receiving while deployment

[image]

Successful deployment of Next js 13 application on self hosting server with different environments.

Comment: Please post the error as text instead of image.

Comment: As the error mentions, you need Node.js 16+ to use the `app` directory in Next.js.